# What are the main differences between a covert timing channel and a covert storage channel?

Tags: exploit, attacks, detection, confidentiality, covert-channel

I am trying to find the differences between a covert timing channel and a covert storage channel in terms of detectability, performance, features, and any other advantages and disadvantages.

Is there any resource that directly compares the advantages and disadvantages of the two attacks?

Comment: Did you try to google that? because there is a lot of information about it, I would recommend you to read the book "Hiding in Plain Sight: Steganography and the Art of Covert Communication" from Eric Cole

Comment: Some of the first search results: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/515.html and https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/385.html